# How do I setState properly in a functional React component?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, react-hooks, state

I have implemented React State Hook in a functional React component like this:

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
```

In my component I perform an Asynchronous API request and fill a table with the result:

```
const loadArtikel = () =>
    fetch("https://my-api.com/api/v1/xyz")
        .then(res => (res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res)))
        .then(res => res.json())


return (
    <Async promiseFn={loadArtikel}>
        {({ data, err, isLoading }) => {
            if (isLoading) return (<div>Loading...</div>)
            if (err) return `Something went wrong: ${err.message}`

            if (data) {
                var tempData = [];
                Object.keys(data.artikel).map(function (keyName, keyIndex) {
                    tempData.push(data.artikel[keyName]);
                });
                setTableData(tempData); // this line is causing problems
                return (
                    <MaterialTable
                        data={tableData}
                    />
                )
            }
        }}
    </Async>
);
```

When I use `setTableData()`, this leads to the fetch request being repeated over and over.
I can't tell why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually causing an infinite loop, as the component will re-render each time its props/state changes. In this case, you are directly calling `setTableData` within the return of your component, which updates the state. This will in turn cause the component to re-render again, thus causing the request to be called over and over again.

If this method is meant to be called only once, you should be using it within the `useEffect` hook, with an empty array as the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {  
  fetch('https://my-api.com/api/v1/xyz')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      // process data
      const tempData = ......;
      setTableData(tempData);
    });     
}, []);


return (
  <>
  {
    tableData.length 
      ? (
        <MaterialTable
          data={tableData}
        />
      : <div>Loading...</div>
  } 
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Solved my problem.